# How to concatenate CSV rows into new rows?

Tags: php, csv

Consider the following data.csv:

```
 "1", "2", "3", "4"
 "5", "6", "7", "8"
 "9","10","11","12"
"13","14","15","16"
"17","18","19","20"
"21","22","23","24"
"25","26","27","28"
"29","30","31","32"
"33","34","35","36"
```

In reality, the rows and columns are much longer, but the principle stays the same.

I need a way to read the csv file, remove the quotes and concatenate every 3 consecutive rows to each other to format the following output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36
```

I now have:

```
$path = "data.csv";
$row = 0;
$newrow = 0;
$newrows = array();
if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $newrows[$newrow] = implode("," $data);
    if ($row % 3) $newrow++;
    $row++;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create an array "newrows" (see below) in which data is added to the current new row while $row cannot be devided by 3

```
$newrows = array (
  [0] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
  [1] = "13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24",
  [2] = "25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36"
)
```

My code obviously isn't working, but I am confused as how to proceed. Do you know? Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

`edit` I seem to have made a mistake. The output should not be "concatenate every set of 3 rows" but rather "concatenate every third row", so:

- every 3rd row is concatenated to the previous 3rd one
- row 4 (1 + 3) and 7 (1 + 3 + 3) are concatenated to row 1
- row 5 (2 + 3) and 8 (2 + 3 + 3) are concatenated to row 2
- row 6 (3 + 3) and 9 (3 + 3 + 3) are concatenated to row 3

The output then would be an array:

```
array (
  [0] => 1,2,3,4,13,14,15,16,25,26,27,28
  [1] => 5,6,7,8,17,18,19,20,29,30,31,32
  [2] => 9,10,11,12,21,22,23,24,33,34,35,36
)
```

I tried this but it concatenates incorrect:

```
$path = "data.csv";
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
      if ($row % $i == 0) $newrows[$i] .= implode(",", $data);
    }
    $row++;
  }
}

print_r($newrows);

Array (
  [1] => 1,2,3,45,6,7,89,10,11,1213,14,15,1617,18,19,2021,22,23,2425,26,27,2829,30,31,3233,34,35,36
  [2] => 5,6,7,813,14,15,1621,22,23,2429,30,31,32
  [3] => 9,10,11,1221,22,23,2433,34,35,36
)
```

P.S. In reality, the csv is much larger and I need every 147th row to be concatenated to the previous 147th row, but the principle is the same I guess.

Comment: What is the output of your code as it is today?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your while loop needs some work:

```
$newrow = 0; $row = 1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if( !isset( $newrows[$newrow])) $newrows[$newrow] = '';
    $newrows[$newrow] .= implode(",", $data);
    if ($row % 3 == 0) {
        $newrow++;
    } else {
        $newrows[$newrow] .= ', ';
    }
    $row++;
}
```

Notable changes:

- `$row` now starts at 1, so the first three iterations will be mapped to the same entry.
- `$newrows[$newrow] = '';` is properly initialized.
- `$row % 3` is compared to `== 0`, which determines if we're at the end of every third row correctly.
- `$newrows[$newrow]` is set to `.= implode(",", $data);`, which will continually concatenate rows together. Otherwise, only the last iteration would be kept in your original code.

Comment: Shouldn't you check if $newrows[$newrow] exists before using .= to prevent index not found error ? This still is the correct answer.

Comment: @nickb Thanks - it outputs `Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,45,6,7,89,10,11,12 [1] => 13,14,15,1617,18,19,2021,22,23,24 [2] => 25,26,27,2829,30,31,3233,34,35,36 )` - in other words no comma concatenating the old rows (eg between 4 and 5). I tried `implode(",", $data) . ",";` but then the comma is also concatenated to the end of each $newrow. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pr0no - Sure, just add the `else` statement I just updated into my answer.

Comment: @nickb I seem to have made a mistake in defining the problem. Please refer to the `edit` in the opening post. Do you have any ideas? I tried modifying your code, but it has got me puzzled

Comment: @Pr0no - I would revert your edit and open a new question as your current problem is unrelated to your original one